# How to check if a BLE device is currently busy?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I need to check if the device is writing a firmware chunk. If yes, then do not start recording the next chunk. I tried to do it with continuations but it didn't work.

Can a reliable write help me in this situation?

Comment: Are you able to change the sourcecode of the other device? Sounds like some kind of flow control is needed here. The device needs to request the next firmware chunk when ready. What kind of device are we talking about?

Comment: No, I can't change the source code of the device. The device device is a speaker for playing sounds.

Comment: You need to add more info. Is the BLE flow control enough or is additional flow control needed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.